# query ManyToManyfield for requested user

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models, a user model and a sport model. These two models have a m2m relationship as a user can do multiple sports and a sport can be played by more than one user. I want to get a query set of a user's sports, so only the sports a specific user does shows up for that user.

I have created a context_processors.py file so that the information is available on all pages of the site. The problem is that I don't know how to query the database to get this information.

These are my models:

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    

class User(AbstractUser):
   ...
   sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)
```

Right now, I get all the sports available, like this

```
def test(request):
    sports = Sport.objects.all()
    return {
        'x': sports
    }
```

I just want to get the sports the requested user is assigned to in the sports variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are usually two options here:

```
Sport.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

or:

```
request.user.sports.all()
```

both will make the same database query. You should use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to prevent non-authenticated users from visiting the view, since then `request.user` is not a user object. Furthermore a view can *not* return a dictionary: it should return a `HttpResponse` object, for example by rendering a template:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def test(request):
    context = {
        'sports': request.user.sports.all()
    }
    # …
```

Comment: Which one do you recommend to use?

Comment: @RandomMadi: `request.user.sports.all()` since it is shorter.

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware: no, if you define a `ForeignKey`/`ManyToManyField`/`OneToOneField`, Django will add a relation in reverse. See for example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships here we filter with `entry__headline__contains=...`, but there is no `entry` field in `Blog`, it will make a query in the relation reverse. It uses the [**`related_query_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the sports played by the user, you have to filter the sports model queryset specific to the User row.

```
Sports.objects.filter(user__id = request.user.id)
```

Since Sports and User has manytomany relationship, you can access "User" model attribute in Sports model related queries. "id" is the auto-generated key, if you are using any primary key you can replace "id" with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
sports = request.user.sports.all()
```